# trying to create a folder using cmd for reactjs

Tags: reactjs

E:>create-react-app react-app
(node:12408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, mkdir 'E:\react-app'
at Object.mkdirSync (fs.js:1013:3)
at Object.module.exports.makeDirSync (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\node_modules\fs-extra\lib\mkdirs\make-dir.js:101:15)
at createApp (C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:255:6)
at C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\create-react-app\createReactApp.js:226:9
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:12408) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:12408) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Are you using windows ? @aniketh

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.